# How to know if lock screen is protected by finger print authentication

Tags: java, android, android-fingerprint-api, keyguard, system-services

How can i check if the lock screen is protected by finger print authentication not with password or pattern or etc, right now i'm using this but its returning true even if lock screen is protected by password

```
keyguardManager.isKeyguardSecure()
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation:

**[keyguardManager.isKeyguardSecure()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html#isKeyguardSecure()):**

> Return whether the keyguard is secured by a PIN, pattern or password
>   or a SIM card is currently locked.

**[isDeviceSecure](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html#isDeviceSecure())**

> Returns whether the device is secured with a PIN, pattern or password. This doesn't treats SIM locked states as secure

Unfortunately the APIs available doesn't allow us to pin point which type of unlock method has been used by user.

Even if your app has Administrator privileges, there is no direct API available to achieve it (there are some work around with which it can be detected in most of the cases).